# Amazon FSx for openZFS mount connection time out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04, amazon-efs

I have created ubuntu EC2 instance on North Virginia region with custom VPC. I have created file system with Amazon FSx for open ZFS as same subnets and same AZ. I have created two security groups, One for EC2 instance as EFS Target Security group another one for file system as EFS Mount Security group. I added inbound rules SSH and outbound rules NFS Port with destination as Filesystem security group.

[image: EC2 instance Security group inbound rules]

[image: EC2 instance Security group outbound rules]

I added inbound rules NFS Port with source as EC2 instance security group and File system Security group.

[image: AWS FSx openZFS Security group]

Both EC2 instance and File system placed on same subnet and same Availability zone. Finally, i tried to mount this file system on my EC2 instance. However, This mount point not connected. Its throwing connection time out error on ubuntu terminal.

$ sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.2 file-system-endpoint:/fsx/ /home/ubuntu/.wine/drive_c/eagfs/

mount.nfs: Connection timed out

Can any one help me to sort out from this issues?

Comment: Any one can help me?

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Not yet. Did you solved this?

Comment: No, running into same issue... :)

Comment: I am using FSx for NetApp ONTAP and for me the issue was missing route to the FSX Endpoint IP Range in the Routing Table of the EC2 Instance Subnet. We have to add routing entry to the routing table of EC2 instance pointing FSx Endpoint IP Range to the FSx Network Interface. Can you try that?

Comment: I will try one more time and update here

Comment: added my comment as answer, just for anyone searching this in future!

Comment: I have opened All traffic in Openzfs security group. Then its mounted successfully

Answer (score 0):

I am using FSx for NetApp ONTAP and for me the issue was missing route to the FSX Endpoint IP Range in the Routing Table of the EC2 Instance Subnet. We have to add routing entry to the routing table of EC2 instance pointing FSx Endpoint IP Range to the FSx Network Interface.

Also, from AWS documentation, there are couple of things to try, including the routing entry verification.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/ONTAPGuide/unable-to-access.html#subnet-route-tables